# CSS Drop down menu on Internet Explorer 7 bug

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I have a CSS drop down menu built, that is working perfectly of course in Firefox and Chrome. But on Internet explorer 7 and 8, the drop down is moved to the right making it impossible to click the links.

I made a jsFiddle here :
http://jsfiddle.net/xMrPE/

And a screenshot of it under ie7 here :
http://s16.postimg.org/g90wthb2t/image.png

here is the HTML :

```
<div class="menu">
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">La meunerie française</a>
        <ul>
            <li style="margin-left:0;"><a href="conseil.php">Conseil d'administration</a></li>
            <li style="margin-left:0;"><a href="syndicats.php">Syndicats régionaux</a></li>
            <li style="margin-left:0;"><a href="equipe.php">L'équipe</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">La filière</a>
        <ul>
            <li style="margin-left:0;"><a href="entites_analyse.php">Entités techniques de la meunerie</a></li>
            <li style="margin-left:0;"><a href="meunerie_europe.php">Meunerie européenne</a></li>
            <li style="margin-left:0;"><a href="horsue.php">Meunerie hors UE</a></li>
            <li style="margin-left:0;"><a href="organisations.php">Organisations professionnelles</a></li>
            <li style="margin-left:0;"><a href="intercereales.php">Intercéréales</a></li>
            <li style="margin-left:0;"><a href="franceagrimer.php">FranceAgriMer</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Les Moulins</a>
        <ul>
            <li style="margin-left:0;"><a href="regions-meunieres.php">Régions meunières</a></li>
            <li style="margin-left:0;"><a href="regions-administratives.php">Régions administratives</a></li>
            <li style="margin-left:0;"><a href="farines.php?farine_id=">Farines & produits commercialisés</a></li>
            <li style="margin-left:0;"><a href="groupements.php">Groupements meuniers</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Fournisseurs</a>
        <ul>
            <li style="margin-left:0;"><a href="fournisseurs-rubrique.php">Rubrique</a></li>
            <li style="margin-left:0;"><a href="fournisseurs-alphabetique.php">Liste Alphabétique</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The CSS :

```
.menu {
    width:100%;
    height:55px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: #5c4a29;
}

.menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding-top:7px;
    font-size: 11px;
}

.menu ul li {
    float:left;
    margin-left:55px;

}

.menu ul li a {
    color:#ffffff;
    padding-bottom:25px;
}

.menu ul li a:hover, .menu ul li a.actif, .menu ul li:hover > a{
    color:#DDD3AA;
}

.menu ul ul {
    display:none;
}



.menu ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 10000;
    width:210px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    top:55px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
    border-radius: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
    background-color: #5c4a29;
}

.menu ul ul li {
    width:190px;
    padding-left:10px;
    float: left;
    margin-top:10px;
}

.sidebar {
    width:225px;
    min-height:400px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
```

I really can't see why it isn't working correctly.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance !

Sébastien

Comment: The title is NOT self explanatory, it says nothing about your problem.

Comment: Updated with a screenshot explaining the issue better

Comment: jsfiddle is also not working properly in IE .... IE is a nightmare for developer's ...... :)

Comment: jsfiddle only works in IE9 and above.  Which sucks when trying to troubleshoot CB issues. I think the best fix is just tinkering at this point.

Answer (score 1):

For one on line 37 in your css I would change top from 55 to 45 so you can actually select the links. Also on line 1 change your height to 45.

```
.menu ul li:hover > ul {
display: block;
position:absolute;
z-index: 10000;
width:210px;
padding-bottom:20px;
top:45px;
-webkit-border-radius: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
border-radius: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
background-color: #5c4a29;
}

.menu {
width:100%;
height:55px;
float:left;
position:relative;
z-index: 1000;
background-color: #5c4a29;
}
```

Comment: One thing that will help is to use the F12 command when in IE, you can troubleshoot allot of issues with it. Its allot like firebug.

Comment: Yes, the 55 to 45 was updated on the live code.

I just tried the f12 command under my windows vista with ie7 and nothing seems to happen, but i will look into that thank you

Comment: You may have to punch it twice, what version of IE are you up to date with. ie7 is what you said, but is that your document mode or browser mode?

Comment: Hit it twice, still nothing, all updates are done apparently. And I don't know the difference about browser or document mode, i'll google that right now.

Comment: This is true... I give a +1 Spudley!